How do I fix this program in Java that won't rerun the while loop that asks for a continue yes/no?
I have this code to create a triangle which all works fine, but in the while loop I have the user prompted to answer yes or no if they want to make another triangle and regardless of the answer nothing will happen... The program won't rerun nor end.
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Triangle
{
   //this lab is setup with a single static method
   //there are no instance variables or additional methods / constructors

    public String createTriangle( String let, int size)
    {   
        int triangleSize = size;
        String triangleChar = let;
        int sizeTrack = 1;
        String output = "";
        while (sizeTrack <= triangleSize){ //this checks that the size tracker variable is less than the size of the triangle.
         for (int lineTrack = 1; lineTrack <= sizeTrack; lineTrack ++){
            output = output + triangleChar;
          }
          sizeTrack ++;
          output = output + "\n";
        }
      return output;    
    }
public static void main( String args[] )
    {
    Scanner Keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    Triangle test = new Triangle();
    int sizeOfTriangle;
    String triangleCharInput;
    String continueYesNo = "y";
    while (continueYesNo == "y"){
      System.out.println("Please enter the triangle size: "); //this asks the user to input the size the triangle will be.
      sizeOfTriangle = Keyboard.nextInt();
      System.out.println("Please enter the letter the triangle will be: ");
      triangleCharInput = Keyboard.next(); //this sets the triangleCharInput to the user inputted character.
      System.out.println("thank you!");
      System.out.println(test.createTriangle(triangleCharInput, sizeOfTriangle));
      System.out.println("Do you want to make another triangle?");
      if (Keyboard.next().equals("Yes")){
        continueYesNo = "y";
      }
        else if (Keyboard.next().equals("yes")){
        continueYesNo = "y";
      }
        else if (Keyboard.next().equals("Y")){
        continueYesNo = "y";
      }
        else if (Keyboard.next().equals("y")){
        continueYesNo = "y";
      }
        else if (Keyboard.next().equals("YES")){
        continueYesNo = "y";
      }
      else continueYesNo = "n";
     }
    }

}

I have tried changing the continueYesNo variable to a interger or boolean but nothing works regardless of what I try.

regarding, while (continueYesNo == "y"){, don't compare Strings using == or != since this checks for reference equality which is not what you want. Instead use .equals(...) or .equalsIgnoreCase(...) which tests if the characters in two Strings are the same and in the same order.

Wait, you use both the correct String equality check in your if statements and the incorrect check in the while statement. What gives here?

You could get rid of all those ifs and instead do a do { ... } while ((sentinelValue.equalsIgnoreCase("y") || (sentinelValue.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"));

Also, all your if blocks are re-requesting input from the user which doesn't make sense. You want to request the input from the user once by calling .next(), put that value into a variable and then you can test the variable once (as I show above) or as many times as you want without repeatedly making needless and confusing Scanner calls.

@HovercraftFullOfEels the use of == for strings has nothing to do with the cause of this problem, and the duplicate is wrong. Although generally you shouldn't compare strings with ==, in this snippet the == operator is guaranteed to succeed because it is only ever setting continueYesNo to a literal "y" or "n" and only ever comparing it with a literal. Literals are interned. A literal "y" on one line of the program has the same address as a literal "y" on another line of the program, and can be compared using ==. Yes, that's flaky and not recommended, but it's not the cause.

The actual cause of the problem is as @HovercraftFullOfEels explained in their last comment. Not because of ==/equals.
